# SQLITE EXCEPT on a single column

Tags: sqlite, set

I've got two sub-queries on a table, and I want the result to be similar to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition2;
```

However, I only want a single column to be considered for the purpose of this set operation, because the other columns are always different.  Thus, the above query always returns everything in the first set, instead of only those elements which don't appear in the second set (comparing only a single column).

If I was trying to find the UNION I could do it with a JOIN, but since I'm trying to find the complement instead I'm not sure the way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition1
AND someColumn NOT IN (SELECT someColumn
                       FROM table
                       WHERE condition2)
```